# How to Map/Merge multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, mapping

I am new to SQL, I am trying to "map" data from several tables in ONE database to create ONE table with relational information. For example, I am trying to take data from my tables ps3_productcategories, ps3_categories and "map"/"merge" to the ps3_products table,  The previous tables contains all the "category information" needed to map to "correct products".

I am trying to "MAP" the productID to the "correct"=> categoryID=> categoryName=> categoryParent etc.....

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into `views`, it *may* be what you are looking for, although they do not create this in another database they do allow to create virtual tables from existing data.

> A database View is known as a "virtual table" which allows you to query the data in it.

[See the MySql manpage on views.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html).

And [here is a small tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx) on the subject.

If you *really* need this in a seperate database, you can easily create a view and export the results of that, and import it in other database.